# C++ - Why is std::function<some_type_t, void> invalid?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, void

In C++, if I try to do this:

```
std::function<void(bool,void)>
```

then the compiler will throw errors. Why is this? It's useful in many cases. One example:

```
//g++ -std=c++17 prblm.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

template<class type_t>
class some_callback
{
    public:
        using callback_t = std::function<void(bool,type_t)>;
        some_callback(callback_t _myfunc)
        {
            this->myfunc = _myfunc;
        }
        callback_t myfunc;
};

using callback_with_just_bool = some_callback<void>;
using callback_with_an_int_too = some_callback<int>;

int main()
{
    auto my_callback_with_int = callback_with_an_int_too([](bool x, int y)
    {
    }); //OK

    auto my_callback_just_bool = callback_with_just_bool([](bool x)
    {
    }); //Error

    auto my_callback_just_bool = callback_with_just_bool([](bool x,void z)
    {
    }); //Error
    return 0;
}
```

This allows for a very clean syntax if the user would like to optionally have additional data in their callback, but not have to. However, the compiler will reject code that tries to initialize an object of `callback_with_just_bool`

Why is it like this, and is there a clean way around it? Thanks.

Edit: The specific reason I'm trying to do this, in real world code, is in an event system. There is data provided to the event system about an individual object that wishes to *conditionally* receive events (e.x. "if you're close enough to the source, you'll receive a sound event") as well as data provided to a callback *about* the event (e.x. "a 10khz noise at X200 Y200"). Most of the time, the data needed to check the requirements will exist inside the data provided to the callback *about* the event, but I wanted to provided an optional additional data structure if that was not the case. Hence, the user would specify "void" if they didn't need this additional data structure.

Comment: It's like that because `void` is not a valid parameter type.

Comment: Sounds like you need `std::optional` or a pointer for your additional data structure.

Comment: Yea, that would work, but I'm being pedantic about performance because there is a good likelihood that thousands of events are going to be triggered per tick, which will probably 90 ticks per second+ as I am working on a VR game. It'd be cool if there was a type-system equivalent of what std::optional does for values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a proposal to add "regular void" to the language.

In it, void becomes a monostate type that all other types implicitly convert to.

You can emulate this with

```
struct monostate_t {
  template<class T>
  monostate_t(T&&) {}
};
```

then

```
using callback_with_just_bool = some_callback<monostate_t>;
auto my_callback_just_bool = callback_with_just_bool([](bool x, auto&&...)
{
});
```

works roughly as you like.

Comment: Thanks! This will work much better than template specialization since the class I want to use this in is quite complicated.

Answer (score 9):

*"Why is this?"*

Because the only permitted usage of `void` in a parameter list is to show that the function doesn't accept any parameters.

From [[function]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function):

> `void`
>
> Indicates that the function takes no parameters, it is the exact synonym for an empty parameter list: `int f(void);` and `int f();` declare the same function. Note that the type void (possibly cv-qualified) cannot be used in a parameter list otherwise: `int f(void, int);` and `int f(const void);` are errors (although derived types, such as `void*` can be used)

*"Is there a clean way around it?"*

I  would suggest to specialize for `void`:

```
template<class type_t>
class some_callback
{
    std::function<void(bool,type_t)> myfunc;
};

template<>
class some_callback<void>
{
    std::function<void(bool)> myfunc;
};
```

Comment: Fair enough, but the rules seem to decrease the generality of the C++ language IMHO. I don't know why they would make void(void) be valid but void(int, void) be invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Variadic templates are one way to do this:

```
template <class... T>
struct some_callback
{
  std::function<void(bool, T...)> myfunc;
};

using callback_with_just_bool = some_callback<>;
using callback_with_an_int_too = some_callback<int>;
```

This is even cleaner with an alias template:

```
template <class... T> using callback_type = std::function<void(bool, T...)>;

int main()
{
  callback_type<int> my_callback_with_int = [](bool x, int y)
  {
  }; //OK

  callback_type<> my_callback_just_bool = [](bool x)
  {
  }; //OK now too...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might create specialization:

```
template<class type_t>
class some_callback
{
    std::function<void(bool,type_t)> myfunc;
};

template<>
class some_callback<void>
{
    std::function<void(bool)> myfunc;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the code  you showed, it is because in C/C++, you cannot define a function, f, as

```
void f(bool b, void v) {}
```

The reason is that, as @Peter Ruderman said, `void` is not a valid parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have explained the why. This answers "is there a clean way around it?"

What I usually do for callbacks is use lambdas.

```
std::function<void(void)> myfunc;

bool b = false;
int i = 42;

myfunc = [&]() { if (b) ++i; };
```